# Linking error while using Armadillo and Lapack

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, lapack, armadillo

my name is Ulrich and I just started writing  my bachelor thesis, which includes a part where i write a program, which needs a Singular Value Decompostion.
At first i need to say, English is my 2nd language and I'm totally new to programming. So please help me with easy words ;)

After some research, I found that Armadillo offers a good SVD()-function, which is based on the Lapack library, so I downloaded them both and tried to install them correctly, and I think i failed at that part:

So here is the relevant parts of my written code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
    mat A(N,2*N+1, fill::zeros); //the zeroess will be replaced later, don't worry i know a SVD of zeroes is stupid ;)
    mat U;
    mat V;
    vec S=svd(A);
```

The compilation error is:

> undefined reference to 'dgesdd_'

What I use:

- Code Blocks with MinGW compiler (Probably latest version; I installed it 3 days ago).
- Armadillo Library 4.650.4
- Lapack Library 3.5.0
- Windows 8.1

What I have done:
I linked in the settings of Codeblocks the compiler with the Folder containing a lot of .header files from Armadillo (.../include/armadillo_bits/)
and i linked in the same way the Lapack folder with 4 .header files(.../lapacke/include/)
Furthermore the readme from armadillo said I shall comment out certain lines from a file called config.hpp
i looked through the whole file, but i think i don't have to uncomment anything. but just in case you need to see it, I can upload the file for you.

PS: while searching for a solution I came across this question which looked quite similar to my problem and seems to be easy fixable, but unfortunately I don't understand anything of it:
[Question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978742/armadillo-blas-lapack-linking-error)
i hope you can help me with this,
Ulli

Comment: Try using [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) instead of standard BLAS + LAPACK.