# Error when multiplying matrices with armadillo library (CodeBlocks)

Tags: c++, matrix, codeblocks, armadillo

Am  trying to multiply two small matrices but i cant get the code to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>


using namespace std;
using namespace arma;



int main()
{


mat A1(1,2) ;
A1.ones();
mat Theta1(6,1);
Theta1.randn();
mat tool = trans(Theta1);
mat z1= tool*A1;
//cout<<z1<<endl;
cout<<Theta1<<endl;
}
```

I get the following errors

||=== Build: Debug in tutorialpp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN4arma4blas4gemvIdEEvPKcPKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_':|
D:\Downloads\armadillo-7.200.1b\armadillo-7.200.1b\include\armadillo_bits\wrapper_blas.hpp|36|undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemv_'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN4arma4blas4gemmIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_S5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_':|
D:\Downloads\armadillo-7.200.1b\armadillo-7.200.1b\include\armadillo_bits\wrapper_blas.hpp|71|undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemm_'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s)) ===|

Please guide me so i can fix this , thanks

Comment: Undefined reference usually means the linker command is missing a library. Googling "undefined reference towrapper_dgemm_" dug up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978742/armadillo-blas-lapack-linking-error

Comment: ok , probably its a linking problem but how do i properly link armadillo with codeblocks i cant find a proper guide ,this is all new to me

Comment: Why would one want to link an unrelated object file to an IDE? Code::Blocks is not a library. It is also not a compiler or an linker.

Comment: ok maybe a phrased it wrong , i just want to find out how i can make armadillo run properly while i use codeblocks to build the program.

Comment: Somewhere in Code::Blocks you will be able to set the list of libraries the linker will use. Googling "code::blocks linker libraries" finds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks which may or may not be accurate 5 years later, but probably will point you in the right direction. [Get yourself a reliable reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) you can consult for coding tips and proper terminology, and then use the terminology to make Internet searches. They're very handy.